# Can't figure out how to use/work-with, my shell application for javafx projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

What's up yall. I have the newest version of java(17.0.1) and am using the newest version Eclipse IDE. I'm taking a Java college course and our textbook provides code for 2 java applications supposed to be used as a shell app to start all of our JavaFX graphics projects. Now that I have the 2 apps together in the same project file and working correctly, we are supposed to go in and customize the shell application (pictured the class is changed to "DiceRoll". when I go to customize the code for a new project and "save as" the file(as to save my new project while keeping the shell file how it is, Eclipse keeps giving me trouble and not allowing me to save the file to a folder on my C: what am I doing wrong? Thanks[This is picture of the 2 apps straight out of our textbook to be a "shell" or "skeleton code" for new projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1sY2.jpg)

Comment: Probably you don’t have write permission for the location you are trying to save the file.  That is just a guess.  I will remove the JavaFX tag as saving source files is not directly related to JavaFX.  If you can’t get a file copy to work from inside eclipse, just copy the source files using a command line or the file explorer.

Comment: Don’t screenshot code, put it in the question as text formatted as code.